# Linux Route To internet

Tags: linux, networking, routing, subnet, gateway

I have two linux boxes connected to each other via the eth0 port.

From the 1st box (thing 1) I can ping 172.24.2.2, 172.24.1.65 (my laptop wireless connection to the HOSTAPD) and 192.168.1.196 (thing 2 wlan0 connection)

From the 2nd box (thing 2) I can 172.24.2.1, 172.24.1.1 and 192.168.1.1 (internet router)

Since both thing 1 and thing 2 can ping addresses that are on my laptop or assigned by my router that is connected to the internet, why can't I get to the internet on either machine. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I can't quite seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

```
Thing 1:

eth0

IP: 172.24.2.1

wlan0: (HOSTAPD)

IP: 172.24.1.1

sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

route -n

 Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.24.2.2      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.24.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
172.24.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

/etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1

iptables-save

# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Sep 25 11:06:45 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [143:74243]
:INPUT ACCEPT [15:1386]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [40:2905]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [10:927]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 25 11:06:45 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Sep 25 11:06:45 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [474:101797]
:INPUT ACCEPT [279:24338]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [8:536]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [223:24658]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [226:24674]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 25 11:06:45 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Sep 25 11:06:45 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [279:24338]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [5:380]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [222:24698]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT


        ===============================================================================

Thing 2:

eth0

IP: 172.24.2.2

wlan0: (connected to local internet wifi)

IP: 192.168.1.196 

sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.24.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.24.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 wlan0

/etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
#nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Thing 2 has an incorrect default gateway set for Internet access. Let's start with Thing 2 because it is the one with a direct connection to the Internet (if I'm reading your question correctly). It sounds like you want Thing 1 to route through Thing 2 to reach the Internet.

The current Default Gateway on Thing 2 is 172.24.2.1 but that is not the address of the router with an Internet connection. You need to change the default Gateway on Thing 2 to 192.168.1.1 Once you do this you should have working Internet on Thing 2.

Thing 1 is already setup with the IP address of Thing 1 as it's default gateway so that should allow Thing 1 access.